# ROBLOX LUAu | Get all keys and values in a DataStore

Tags: lua, roblox

I was wondering how you could get fetch all data from every player stored in the DB. (So not the players that are in the game, but all players that are stored somehow in the DB.)

I’ve seen things like GetOrderedDataStore, and we’re not going to use that.

yeah that lol

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a regular DataStore with all your player data. But that doesn't allow you to figure out which players are in your game.

If you add a 2nd OrderedDataStore (which only accepts number values) that stores e.g. for each userId the timestamp of when they last played, you can use [GetSortedAsync](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/OrderedDataStore/GetSortedAsync) to go through all these keys. After that, you can simply use the key to get the actual data from your regular DataStore.

To be fair, this isn't scalable. If you have hundreds/thousands of unique players, you'll have to perform **a lot** of Datastore requests.

Alternatively to using (just) a DataStore, you can use the HttpService to also keep (some) data synchronized with an external database. These are much easier to query from.

Comment: Is there anyway to not use OrderedDataStore?

Comment: Without having an external out-of-game database you talk to using HttpService? Not that I know, no.

Comment: What about trying to find out every player that has ever joined the game, I'm pretty sure there is an API for it.

Comment: @salvage_dev An in-game API for that? I've never known of one. Using either OrderedDataStore or HttpService (if you count one) has been the only option for years, although I haven't kept in touch with new features recently.